# My generic decoupling is very ugly

Tags: c#, oop

I am creating a dll that can handle settings and the loading/saving of settings.

I have a settings class with properties like, `string Path`, `DateTime LastOpened`, etc.
The settings can be anything, and the only requirement is that it has a way of defaulting its values.

There is a different class that is responsible for loading/saving the settings. This class can take any settings class and (de-)serialize to any file format. For instance, it could load settings of a type from an XML file or settings of the *same* type from a JSON file.

My design ends up being kind of weird.

I define an interface for all settings classes, so that I know that `DefaultSettings()` is available.

```
interface ISettings<T>
{
    T DefaultSettings();
}
```

My settings class could then look like:

```
public class MySettings : ISettings<MySettings>
{
    public DateTime LastOpened;
    public string Path;

    public MySettings DefaultSettings()
    {
        LastOpened = DateTime.Now;
        Path = @"c:\";
    }
}
```

It looks pretty weird already that the implementing class my tell the interface of it self.

The load/save classes implements this interface:

```
interface ISettingsFile<T>
{
    T Load(string file);
    void Save();
}
```

Suppose I want to load `MySettings` from, say, an `XmlSettingsFile<MySettings>`.
I would have to write something ugly like

```
MySettings mySettings = new MySettings();
XmlSettingsFile<MySettings> file = new XmlSettingsFile<MySettings>();
try {
    mySettings = file.Load();
} catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
    mySettings = mySettings.DefaultSettings();
}
```

This is simply too weird and ugly. There has to be a better way of doing this.

Do you have any good ideas?

Comment: I think the ugly w/ this code is the non-standard tab spaces.. sometimes 2, sometimes 4 ;)

Comment: @Charleh I have a feeling that it could be done more elegant. Maybe like injecting `ISettingsFile` into the settings or something like that.

Comment: In my experience, in order to make a nice generic API you often have to do lots of wacky things behind the scenes to make it simple for the caller.

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to inject it - surely the settings and the mechanism in which the settings are saved are two separate entities and therefore your decoupling is fine. You can use `ISettings` without depending on `ISettingsFile` but `ISettingsFile` requires knowledge of `ISettings` in order to know what to load/save. I'd say you have this spot-on.... I'd also say your API is good - I need a settings loader and a settings class, simple!

Comment: @Charleh and Rory, valuable comments. Maybe I'm over-doubting it.

Comment: One thing I can suggest is that you use a property for the default values instead of a method.

Comment: You might want to add this constraint `interface ISettings<T> where T : ISettings<T>`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that your approach is ugly. It's certainly better using intermediate string representation or something similar.

Therefore I would say **your approach is fine, leave it as it is.**

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
interface ISettings 
{ 

    public string GetSetting(string settingName, string defaultValue);

}
```

so instead of trying to represent the settings as properties you use named values. This makes it easier to think about loading/saving settings and easier to have method overloads for passing responsibility to different classes. You can do this all with dynamic if you like, but personally I like this pattern and it keeps things simple.

You can add generics too, but you typically I find a few methods like this is sufficient:

```
    public bool GetSettingBool(string settingName, bool defaultValue);
```

Comment: A good idea. But this moves problems from compile time to run time in the event that settingName does not exist.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood what you meant by a default. In any case, I think this pattern has merit: as evidenced by the success of javascript etc strong typing isn't always the best solution, and sufficient test coverage should cater for compile-vs-runtime issue of typos in settings. There are lots of advantages to this simple approach. But yeah, not for everyone if you're really keen on strongly-typed settings.

Comment: Loading values from a file into settings, and afterwards calling `GetSetting("non-existing-value", "default")` (by misspelling the setting name for instance), then the outcome becomes a runtime problem instead of being caught by the intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

This would abstract away your reader implementation (xml, json, whatever)...

```
 public interface IConfigurationReader
{
    T Read<T>(string configKey);
}

public class Configuration
{
    private readonly IConfigurationReader _reader;

    public Configuration(IConfigurationReader reader)
    {
        _reader = reader;
    }

    public string Path
    {
        get
        {
            var path = _reader.Read<string>("Path");
            return path;
        }
    }
}

public class ApplicationConfigFileReader : IConfigurationReader
{
    public T Read<T>(string configKey)
    {
        var settingValue = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configKey];
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(settingValue, typeof(T));
    }
}

//sample usage
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationReader reader = new ApplicationConfigFileReader();
        var config = new Configuration(reader);
        Console.WriteLine(config.Path);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

My Reader implementation simply acts as an adapter over the framework types that are for reading application configuration files.

If you have a lot of settings, it can be beneficial to group them by category/area into separate interfaces.